# why 'this' is undefined in vue2.0, but I can see 'this' in chrome debugger viewer?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, undefined, this, arrow-functions

here is the code:

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
      <button
        @click="() => this.search()"
      >btn1</button>

      <button
        @click="() => this.search1()"
      >btn2</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  methods: {
    search: () => {
      console.log(this);
      //debugger
    },
    search1: function() {
      console.log(this);
      //debugger
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

when I click 'btn1' , the console show "undefined".

when click 'btn2', the console show vuecomponent.

I'm so confuse why 'this' is undefined?

---

Then I found stranger thing,

when use debugger for breakpoint debugging where the console prints ‘undefined’

I can see the value of ‘this’ again. Why?

see:

[strange thing scrennshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Jxzi.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's explained in the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#methods):

> Note that you should not use an arrow function to define a method (e.g. `plus: () => this.a++`). The reason is arrow functions bind the parent context, so `this` will not be the Vue instance as you expect and `this.a` will be undefined.

Comment: thank you :)   but when use debugger for breakpoint debugging where the console prints ‘undefined’, I can see the value of ‘this’ again, can you explain it?   thanks,   see:[https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Jxzi.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Jxzi.png)

Comment: That should not happen. `this` really is `undefined`. Maybe try viewing the script source without the source map.